# ListView in C# 2005 : 20110826n01

Tags: c#, listview, apache-poi

Is it possible to add a checked box in second column of Listview? How?

C# 2005.

Comment: Put table in listview and make 2 colulmn, put checkbox in second column

Comment: I don't know the C# controls but in general in Windows you need to implement this sort of thing yourself, though I wouldn't be surprised if the C# control had some extra functionality over the base Windows control. Curiousity: why have you put today's date in the subject line?

Comment: Why are there dates in the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) there is also the [XpTable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xptable/)